# Updated: SpringBoot inside docker container fails to connect to database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

**[Update]: I noticed that the real problem may be that the tomcat server isn't started (only in the jar, when running with IntelliJ all seems to be working fine)**

I have a docker compose file that defines two services: database and backend.
Backend is a Springboot application. For some reason if i run the application locally (but connecting to the database container) it works, but when i run it on docker it fails to connect to the database. Or at least it seems so, I'm not sure what the real problem is and i haven't been abe to find a solution.

here are my files:

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      networks:
       - my_network

  backend:
    image: eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy
    container_name: backend
    restart: no
    volumes:
      - ./backend/out/artifacts/backend_jar/:/app/
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
    command: /bin/sh -c "cd app && java -jar backend.jar || sleep 2073600"
    networks:
      - my_network

volumes:
  mysql-data:

networks:
  my_network:
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:mysql}:3306/root
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

and this is the error i get when i run on docker:

```
2024-02-05 09:30:57   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2024-02-05 09:30:57  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2024-02-05 09:30:57 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2024-02-05 09:30:57  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2024-02-05 09:30:57   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2024-02-05 09:30:57  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2024-02-05 09:30:57  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)
2024-02-05 09:30:57 
2024-02-05 09:30:57 08:30:57.194 [main] INFO com.example.backend.BackendApplication -- Starting BackendApplication using Java 17.0.10 with PID 7 (/app/backend.jar started by root in /app)
2024-02-05 09:30:57 08:30:57.198 [main] INFO com.example.backend.BackendApplication -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-05 09:30:57 08:30:57.959 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-02-05 09:30:58 08:30:58.041 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 69 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-02-05 09:30:58 08:30:58.508 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-02-05 09:30:58 08:30:58.757 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -- HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:9ad12d1c-0bbc-4e56-82ed-3539a4fa97e5 user=SA
2024-02-05 09:30:58 08:30:58.759 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-02-05 09:30:58 08:30:58.810 [main] INFO org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper -- HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-02-05 09:30:58 08:30:58.888 [main] INFO org.hibernate.Version -- HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version [WORKING]
2024-02-05 09:30:58 08:30:58.931 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator -- HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-02-05 09:30:59 08:30:59.221 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo -- No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-02-05 09:30:59 08:30:59.941 [main] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version -- HV000001: Hibernate Validator null
2024-02-05 09:31:00 08:31:00.876 [main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator -- HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-02-05 09:31:00 08:31:00.933 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -- Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-02-05 09:31:01 08:31:01.542 [main] INFO com.example.backend.BackendApplication -- Started BackendApplication in 4.587 seconds (process running for 4.92)
2024-02-05 09:31:01 08:31:01.550 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -- Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-02-05 09:31:01 08:31:01.563 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-02-05 09:31:01 08:31:01.566 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the error log in plain text?  What is the actual error?  It doesn't look like the `backend` container is using Docker as anything more than a path to get a JVM; could you run the database in a container but the application directly on the host?

Comment: @DavidMaze at the first occasion I have I’ll remove the image and put the text, I’m sorry I didn’t know I wasn’t supposed to post the image. Yes, with the database in the container and the application directly on the host there wasn’t any problem and the application worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only thing that worked was to build with maven directly inside the container. Not sure why nor my preferred solution but it works